# Storing Methods in an Enum?

Tags: java, enums

Right now, I have an enum for a variety of values, and I was wondering if there is any way I would be able to store a method in an enum. For example:

```
public enum myEnum{

     one("first", callFirstMethod),
     two("second", callSecondMethod), 
     three("last", callThirdMethod);

     public String message;
     public Method met;

     myEnum(String m, Method meth){
         message = m;
         met = meth;
     }
}

public class myMethods{
    public void callFirstMethod(){
        System.out.println("First!");
    }

    public void callSecondMethod(){
        System.out.println("Second!");
    }

    public void callThirdMethod(){
        System.out.println("Third!");
    }
}
```

Then by using something like:
    Method method = myEnum.one.callFirstMethod();

To call the method. Is something like this possible? I've tried playing around/looking around on google, and nothing is really turning up. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Look into reflection.

Comment: Why? Why not just *declare* the methods in the Enum and its values?

Comment: What java version are you using? Java 8 allows to adress Methods directly, before that you definately need reflection.

Comment: `enum` is just a special type of class.  Yes you can store methods within it, just declare them as you would for any other class...

Comment: The difficulty comes when there are different parameters that need to be used, particularly instances of other classes. How could I say just use this method, but have put in the arguments outside of the methods. Like: myEnum.one.callFirstMethod(1).

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thank you for the help! I thought it was instances of classes, not actually classes used in getMethod()

Answer (score 2):

Use an interface and have the interface instance as the second enum parameter, or give it an abstract method that is implemented in the instance. For instance:

```
enum MyEnum {

   ONE("first", new MyInterface() {

      @Override
      public void commonMethod() {
         System.out.println("First!");
      }
   }) {
      @Override
      public void abstractEnumMethod() {
         System.out.println("abstract enum meuthod, first!");
      }
   }, 
   TWO("second", new MyInterface() {

      @Override
      public void commonMethod() {
         System.out.println("Second!");
      }
   }) {
      @Override
      public void abstractEnumMethod() {
         System.out.println("abstract enum meuthod, second!");
      }
   }, 
   THREE("last", new MyInterface() {

      @Override
      public void commonMethod() {
         System.out.println("Third!");
      }
   }) {
      @Override
      public void abstractEnumMethod() {
         System.out.println("abstract enum meuthod, third!");
      }
   };

   private String message;
   private MyInterface myType;

   private MyEnum(String m, MyInterface myType) {
      message = m;
      this.myType = myType;
   }

   public String getMessage() {
      return message;
   }

   public MyInterface getMyType() {
      return myType;
   }

   public void enumMethod() {
      System.out.println(message);
   }

   public abstract void abstractEnumMethod();
}

interface MyInterface {
   void commonMethod();
}
```

Comment: or just `public abstract void commonMethod();` in the enum so you don't need to type new MyInterface and create an interface in the source too.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno: thank you, that is correct. I will show that as an option that can be done as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer all depends on what it's you want to achieve.  For example, you could provide a common method within you `enum` and inspect the instance of the enum calling it...

```
public class TestEnum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyEnum.ONE.doStuff();
        MyEnum.TWO.doStuff();
        MyEnum.THREE.doStuff();
    }

    public enum MyEnum {

        ONE("first"),
        TWO("second"),
        THREE("last");

        public String message;

        MyEnum(String m) {
            message = m;
        }

        public void doStuff() {
            System.out.println(name());
            if (ONE.equals(this)) {
                System.out.println("...Do stuff for one");
            } else if (TWO.equals(this)) {
                System.out.println("...Do stuff for two");
            } else if (THREE.equals(this)) {
                System.out.println("...Do stuff for three");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which outputs...

```
one
...Do stuff for one
two
...Do stuff for two
three
...Do stuff for three
```